# Azure ServiceBus Premium - he maximum message size quota exceeded

Tags: azureservicebus

I have created a Azure-ServiceBus in premium tier with units set to 16. And added a queue with `MaxMessageSize =  30,000KB`
However when I try to post a message, i get an error saying,

```
<Error>
    <Code>413</Code>
    <Detail>The maximum message size quota for **outgoing** messages (1114112) has been exceeded. TrackingId:742a2737-76ca-424c-959c-32fac11139ca_G4S1, SystemTracker:healthcheck-poc:Queue:poc-images, Timestamp:2021-08-06T03:00:06</Detail>
</Error>
```

Could someone please suggest me what settings should fix this up..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 16 messaging units. As long as your namespace is Premium it should work. The feature is in public preview so there's a chance that your namespace had a problem with that entity. Either try to recreate it or use the tracking code you've received and open a support case with Azure support.